# decoding and encoding array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays

Can i decode and encode an array in ths way??

```
NSMutableArray *arr;

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder 
{ 
   [coder encodeInt:arr forKey:@"Array"]; 
} 

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder 
{ 
   NSMutableArray array;
   array = [[decoder decodeIntForKey:@"Array"]copy]; 
   return self; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**It will not encode/decode the `NSMutableArray` that way.**

If objects in your array implement `NSCoding` protocol then you can encode array by calling:

```
NSMutableArray * myMutableArray = ...
NSData* myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myMutableArray];
```

And reverse with:

```
NSMutableArray* myMutableArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver
                                             unarchiveObjectWithData:myData];
```